# Custom 404 error page issue

Tags: 7, theming

I want to have a custom 404 page that displays some additional information. I need to display the requested path that was not found and some pages suggestions based on that path (this is based on some internal logic that I don't think is relevant to my question).

Here is what I did:

I defined the default 404 page to be `page-not-found` in `admin/config/system/site-information`

Then in my module I used `hook_page_alter()` to define my pages suggestions (if `drupal_get_http_headers("status")` is `404 Not Found`), and the `request_uri()` to be shown on the 404 template page I created.

I have tried to save these values in different ways (session variable, ctools cache, everything I have tried leads to the same issue — see below).

In **mymodule.module**:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_menu
 * @return mixed
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['page-not-found'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page_not_found',
    'file' => 'inc/functions.inc',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implement hook_theme
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_page_not_found' => array(
      'template' => 'templates/404',
    ),
  );
}
```

In **inc/functions.inc**:

```
function mymodule_page_not_found() {

  return theme('mymodule_page_not_found');
}
```

Problem is, if I request a non existing URL for example `mysite.com/not-found-page-1` then request `mysite.com/not-found-page-2` the information displayed on the 404 page template when I query the *not-found-page-2* corresponds to the values I saved when requesting *not-found-page-1*.

Any idea why I always get the data of the previous query?

Comment: Yes and no. But for now, no. I'd first like to understand why my code behaves this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is, `hook_page_alter()` is called after your theme function is called.  So if you're setting things there it's too late.

I don't know why you're doing it this way.  Why not generate your suggestions in your page callback: `mymodule_page_not_found()`.  Then pass them to the theme function.

Something like this:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_theme
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_page_not_found' => array(
      'template' => 'templates/404', // Not relevant to your question, but you should consider renaming this to mymodule-page-not-found because of a "bug" in D7; see discussion here: https://www.drupal.org/node/342350
      'variables' => array('suggestions' => array()),
    ),
  );
}

function mymodule_page_not_found() {
  // ... generate list of $suggestions ...
  return theme('mymodule_page_not_found', array('suggestions' => $suggestions));
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's also what I thought regarding the hook_page_alter. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is way easier and works just fine! :) And thanks for the additional information too.

Comment: Quick question: I didn't add `'variables' => array('suggestions' => array())` to my code and it works. Why should I add that part?

Comment: It's the more proper way to do it as it offers a form of documentation for folks who want to know what the template expects.  More practically, it provides a way for you to pass in default values in case anyone ever calls your theme function/template without providing a list of suggestions.